# Can I automatically extend lines from SVG?

Tags: svg

I imported an SVG into blender. I have a bunch of lines that don't intersect that I would like to intersect. Is there a way to automatically extend these? And if not, how do I even manually extend them? When I try to rectangle select, nothing is selected:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any automatic method to do it. If they are co-planar you can:

- select the vertices you want to extend
- press <kbd>G</kbd> to activate the move tool, and press <kbd>G</kbd> *again* to limit their movement to their local axes, i.e. their edges
- still in the move tool, press <kbd>C</kbd> or hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> to release the clamp so they can move beyond the edges they're on, but still in the same direction
- move them past the intersection line, left click to finalize the move
- delete excess vertices by *X > Vertices*

[image]

Make sure *[Auto Merge Vertices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6rXF.png)* is active in *Edit Mode*, otherwise it won't split the edges and create new vertices at the intersection points.